# Manipulate RFC 2822 email in javascript

Tags: javascript, email, google-chrome-extension, gmail-api, rfc2822

I am creating a chrome extension which works with the gmail api. The email format followed is based on RFC 2822. I want to modify the email. Is there any standard library in javascript to manipulate the RFC 2822 compliant email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really like [Mailparser](https://github.com/andris9/mailparser) by andris9. It is made for Node, but you can  browserify it or get inspiration from the source.

When you have parsed it, you can manipulate it with his other library, [Mailcomposer](https://github.com/andris9/mailcomposer).